# Custom WPF dialog window causes shell window to close immediately after .Show called

Tags: wpf, windows, c#-4.0, modal-dialog, prism-4

OK. A bit of setup.

I have a small PRISM based app using Unity.

I created a class (separate from the main program where the shell window is) that contains it's own WPF window to pop up as a dialog box while an update is running.

The class does some file copying (real simple stuff just as a PoC) and the window updates the user to its progress.

The window is shown modally (.ShowDialog();) so that it blocks the thread while the update runs.

The update is run off of the ContentRendered event.

When the update finishes, .Close() is called on the window.

This class is instantiated and the update process started (by calling a public function on the class called StartUpdate()), in the OnStartup event in the main program's App.xaml.cs file.

After that, a bootstrapper is created and run.

Finally, in the bootstrapper class, some modules are loaded (they don't do anything except for register a view), and the shell window is resolved and shown in the override of InitializeShell.

All pretty standard stuff, except that the program just closes after it exits InitializeShell. If I don't call .Close in the updater class and let the user close the custom dialog with the X, the same thing happens. I also tried showing the dialog in a non-modal way (just .Show()) and the rest of the program works fine. However, the process does not block so the update would happen after or while the main program loaded. And that would be pointless. I have found a few ways around this. I'm just curious if anyone can explain the behavior.

**Edit: An example code snippet:**
When the user closes the Window1 window, the MainWindow never loads.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml. This is where the program starts.
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        dialogWPF.Class1 c = new dialogWPF.Class1();

        c.Update();

        //After this, the program should continue as normal (Open the MainWindow window)
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the code for Class1 that is called in App.xaml.cs
/// </summary>
public class Class1
{
    private Window1 _win;

    public Class1()
    {
        _win = new Window1();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        _win.ShowDialog();
    }



}
```

Comment: Could you describe what is happening in code; that's a bit fluffy and it's a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Change your shutdown mode to explicit

Comment: You need to trim it down to sample code to reproduce and post that

Comment: Can your dialog just return a `DialogResult` instead of calling `Close()`, my suspicion is that since the dialog is created first it becomes the applications MainWindow so calling close exits the process.

Comment: I'll have to check out setting the shutdown mode to explicit. As far as a DialogResult being returned, no info is actually returned from the window, it's just there to let the user know what's happening. Though I do expect that it's becoming the apps MainWindow some how.

Comment: Post your bootstrapper code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Do you set the shell window as the applications main window like this:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = shell;
```

in the `InitializeShell()` override? Otherwise your update dialog might be the applications main window and cause the application to quit after it has been closed.

Comment: Yes, I have the shell set like that in the InitializeShell() override.